# Matrix for rotation around a vector without using rodrigues rotation formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, rotations

for example how can I write the rotation matrix around the vector $\vec v = (1,1,1)$ with the angle 60°.

I searched all the other questions and they all say that rodrigues rotation formula is the way to go but I'm wondering if there's an easy way for me.

thanks.

Comment: Define "an easy for me".

Comment: as in not using the rodrigues rotation formula, basically any other alternatives. I like choosing @user10354138

Comment: Then you will need to do a lot more work.  For example, pick a rotation to send $(1,1,1)$ to the positive $z$-axis (e.g., by choosing an appropriate oriented orthonormal basis), do the rotation by 60 degrees, then rotate back.

Comment: @user10354138 I think I will just try to understand the rodrigues way. thanks  alot

Comment: The Rodrigues formula is spelled out explicitly here, in case you have not figured it out: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RodriguesRotationFormula.html